Can multiple threads writing an int value to the same location in global memory result in the final value being solely from one thread
For example, if two threads need to simultaneously write two int values to the same address in global memory: int_1 [byte1, byte2, byte3, byte4] and int_2 [byte5, byte6, byte7, byte8], would the data ultimately stored at that address be either int_1 or int_2, rather than a mixture like [byte1, byte2, byte7, byte8] simultaneously from both threads?
Achitecture: Ampere and Hopper

The answer is: it depends, but normally your hypothesis is correct.
If the code in question is executing the 32 bit store using a 32 bit store instruction, then yes, the contents of the 4 bytes will come from one of the competing threads. There are no guarantees about which thread that will be.
But be aware that there are also sub 32 bit memory store operations and if the compiler needs to (alignment, or compiler options for example), it could potentially emit code which will execute multiple  operations to store that 32 bits of data.
In summary, you need to look at the code generated by the compiler to be 100% sure, but if there are two competing threads trying to store to memory using a single instruction, the contents, while undefined, will come completely from one of those competing threads.
